# Error in ARM/Bicep template using deploymentScript running Azure command

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep, azure-rbac

I have a Bicep template with a deployment script in it deploymentScript that should execute a certain Azure command.

But when I run my template it returns this error when it runs the deploymentScript:

> The service does not have access to
> '/subscriptions/3449f684-xxxx-xxxxx/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/my-vault-name'
> Key Vault. Please make sure that you have granted necessary
> permissions to the service to perform the request operation

I have setup a Managed Identity and added Administrator roles to it for the KeyVault.

[image]

In KeyVault I have RBAC enabled. When I check the Access Policies in KeyVault then I do see that the Managed Identity is linked to it.

[image]

I would say it's even an overkill of Roles added to it.

Then lastly, my deploymentScript is setup like this:

```
resource siteCertificatesScript 'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2020-10-01' = {
  name: 'siteCertificates'
  location: location
  kind: 'AzurePowerShell'
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '/subscriptions/3449f684-xxxx-xxxx/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/my-vault-name': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    azPowerShellVersion: '8.3'
    scriptContent: '$Secure_String_Pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "MyPassword" -AsPlainText -Force; 
         Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName "${keyVaultName}" -Name "${resourcePrefix}-cert-signing" -CertificateString "${certSigningBase64}" -Password $Secure_String_Pwd'
    timeout: 'PT1H'
    cleanupPreference: 'OnSuccess'
    retentionInterval: 'P1D'
  }
}
```

But why does my deploymentScript fails with the message that it doesn't have enough rights?

I don't see what I'm forgetting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to grant the `Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/deploy/action` permission to the identity that is deploying the arm/bicep template. I think the Key Vault Administrator roles does not have this permission:

[image]

This is a keyvault provider permission, it is separate from the other `microsoft.resources` permissions.

Please take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/key-vault-parameter?tabs=azure-cli#grant-deployment-access-to-the-secrets

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I had to create a custom role and add the `Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/certificates/*/action` permissions to it. Then added this role to my Managed Identity. Added the role on all Resource Type levels -> `Key Vault`, `Resource Group` and `Subscription`. Now through trial and error I have to figure out the minimal settings

Comment: Awesome!! Glad it was resolved.